# How would you model an Email app in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, nosql

How would you model an email app (like gmail) in MongoDB?  Would you model a `Conversation`? `Inbox` / `OutBox`? or `mail`?

Thanks

Comment: found this, and they model Email http://www.slideshare.net/ibwhite/mongodb-in-production-at-sailthru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail use concept of labels (like tags on stackoverflow). That mean that inbox, send mail, starred, etc normal Email object, just marked with specified label. So, there are only `Email` and `Labels`.

You can see it using search in gmail like `label:inbox` or `label:Starred`.

I'd like to suggest a fairly simple design like this:

```
Email
    {
      _id
      Title,
      Body,
      Status {read, unread},
      Labels { name, type(system, custom) },
      Replies {...},
      ..
    }

Labels
    {
      _id,
      name,
      settings {
              ShowInLabelsList (show, hide, showIfUnread),
              ShowInMessageList (show, hide),
              ..
               }
     }
```

For sure i've missed something, but i guess it's okay to start from above schema and add more features in future if neeed.

**Update:**

For the 'Conversation View' i guess all replies show go to the nested collection `Replies` (i've update my schema). Logic is following:

Once you have received a new message you need check if email with same name already exists (for sure need to Remove 'Re', etc..) also need to check that user that has sent email in list of recipients. If above conditions is true then just add new email to nested collection of `Replies` otherwise add to collection of emails.

Comment: @Bugai13: no, Henry talks about "email threads", i.e. grouping mails by subjects (it's probably a little more complex than just "group by subject").

Comment: thx, what would u put inside Replies?  The actual mail or... _id of the actual mail?

Comment: @Henry: It's mongodb, embedding, embedding... So, i would put actual mails to the Replies collection. Replies it's collection of same documents as parent Email (mb except `Replies`).

Comment: @Bugai Oh, then you're really modeling a Conversation.  How about... embedding all Conversation's into MailBox'es?  is that way too crazy?

Comment: @Henry I have a hard time knowing what to embed as well. It seems the limit we're working with is the document-size. It's got a hard limit of 16mb, but I would guess a 15mb mailbox would be slow if you loaded the whole thing.  I've seen people recommend a collection-per-conversation. I'm considering having a Conversation collection as described above, but then you have to limit each conversation to 16mb (should be reasonable).